# when using this to create new object in Javascript function, I get back undefined

Tags: javascript

```
const john = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Smith",
    mass: 92,
    height: 1.95,
    calcBMI: function() {
        this.bmi = this.mass / (this.height ** 2);
        return this.bmi;
    }
};

console.log(john.bmi)
```

I get an undefined value, I'm confused because when my professor plugged it in, it returned the correct value it should have.

Comment: Did your professor call `john.calcBMI()` before `console.log(john.bmi)`?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const john = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Smith",
    mass: 92,
    height: 1.95,
    calcBMI: function() {
        this.bmi = this.mass / (this.height ** 2);
        return this.bmi;
    }
};
john.calcBMI();
console.log(john.bmi)
```

You need to invoke the calcBMI function for there to be a property called bmi with a valid value ... Otherwise it would always return undefined.